# Build link for javascript into new tabs for <option> tag

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

i have this html code

```html
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html dir="rtl">
<head>


<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>country and city list</title>
<script language="javascript">
function websv(state)
{
 with(document.getElementById('city')) 
 {
  options.length = 0;

  if(state == 0)
  {
   options[0] = new Option('select your country' , '0');
  }
  
  if(state == 1)
  {
   options[0] = new Option('select your country' , '0');
   options[1] = new Option('country1-asia' , '33131');
   options[2] = new Option('country2-asia' , '31541');
  }
  if(state == 2)
  {
   options[0] = new Option('select your country' , '0');
   options[1] = new Option('country3-european' , '43591');
   options[2] = new Option('country4- europeasn' , '43891');
  }
  
 }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

 <select name="state" onChange="websv(this.value);">
  <option value="0">country name</option>
  <option value="1">country1</option>
  <option value="2">country2</option>
 </select>
 <select name="city" id="city">
  <option value="0">please select your country</option>
 </select>

</body>
</html>
```

now i need when user select "country3-european" open new tab by custom link,example: "country3-european.com"

i used many function for javascript, but i can`t set it and have problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
https://jsfiddle.net/kqcLy952/4/

What you were missing was to update the value of your new options. Likewise, to open a new tab, you need to update your window.location as a new function. Here's the working JSFiddle:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html dir="rtl">
<head>


<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>country and city list</title>
<script language="javascript">
function websv(state)
{
    with(document.getElementById('city')) 
    {
        options.length = 0;

        if(state == 0)
        {
            options[0] = new Option('select your country' , '0');
        }

        if(state == 1)
        {
            options[0] = new Option('select your country' , '0');
            options[1] = new Option('country1-asia' , 'http://www.google.com');
            options[2] = new Option('country2-asia' , 'http://www.yahoo.com');
        }
        if(state == 2)
        {
            options[0] = new Option('select your country' , '0');
            options[1] = new Option('country3-european' , 'http://www.facebook.com');
            options[2] = new Option('country4- europeasn' , 'http://www.instagram.com');
        }

    }
}
function openWindow(select) {
  window.open(select);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

    <select name="state" onChange="websv(this.value);">
        <option value="0">country name</option>
        <option value="1">country1</option>
        <option value="2">country2</option>
    </select>
    <select name="city" id="city" onChange="openWindow(this.value)">
        <option value="0">please select your country</option>
    </select>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Also - don't forget your URLs need to have http:// in front, country3-european.com will produce a relative path with your current referring url.

Try it in the JSFiddle

Comment: If this answer worked for you, please accept it this as solved.